# 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' in Specflow C#

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2019, specflow

I am getting an error that says:

> 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'UserName'

Here is my code also it Specflow, Selenium, and Visual Studio

**Scenario**

```
Feature: OasisLogin
    Login to Oasis application

Scenario: Perform Login to Oasis application site
    Given I launch the application
    #And I click login link
    And I enter the following details
    | UserID   | Password |
    | admin    | password |
    And I click login button
    Then I should see Dashboard details link
```

**Step Definition**

```cs
namespace OasisSpecFlowTest.StepDefinition
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class OasisSteps
    {
        OasisLoginPage oasisLoginPage = null;

        [Given(@"I launch the application")]
        public void GivenILaunchTheApplication()
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://oasis.com/Login.aspx");
            oasisLoginPage = new OasisLoginPage(webDriver);
        }

        //[Given(@"I click login link")]
        //public void GivenIClickLoginLink()
        //{
           // oasisLoginPage.ClickLogin();
        //}

        [Given(@"I enter the following details")]
        public void GivenIEnterTheFollowingDetails(Table table)
        {
            dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
            oasisLoginPage.Login((string)data.UserId, (string)data.Password);
        }

        [Given(@"I click login button")]
        public void GivenIClickLoginButton()
        {
            oasisLoginPage.ClickLoginButton();
        }

        [Then(@"I should see Dashboard details link")]
        public void ThenIShouldSeeDashboardDetailsLink()
        {
            Assert.That(oasisLoginPage.IsEmployeeDetailsExist(), Is.True);
        }

    }
}

namespace OasisSpecFlowTest.StepDefinition
{
    [Binding]
    public sealed class OasisSteps
    {
        OasisLoginPage oasisLoginPage = null;

        [Given(@"I launch the application")]
        public void GivenILaunchTheApplication()
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://oasis.com/Login.aspx");
            oasisLoginPage = new OasisLoginPage(webDriver);
        }

        //[Given(@"I click login link")]
        //public void GivenIClickLoginLink()
        //{
           // oasisLoginPage.ClickLogin();
        //}

        [Given(@"I enter the following details")]
        public void GivenIEnterTheFollowingDetails(Table table)
        {
            dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
            oasisLoginPage.Login((string)data.UserId, (string)data.Password);
        }

        [Given(@"I click login button")]
        public void GivenIClickLoginButton()
        {
            oasisLoginPage.ClickLoginButton();
        }

        [Then(@"I should see Dashboard details link")]
        public void ThenIShouldSeeDashboardDetailsLink()
        {
            Assert.That(oasisLoginPage.IsEmployeeDetailsExist(), Is.True);
        }

    }
}
```

**Selenium Page**

```cs
namespace OasisSpecFlowTest.Pages
{
    class OasisLoginPage
    {
        public IWebDriver WebDriver { get; }

        public OasisLoginPage(IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            WebDriver = webDriver;
        }

        //UI Elements
        //public IWebElement InkLogin => WebDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Login"));

        public IWebElement TxtUserID => WebDriver.FindElement(By.Name("User ID"));

        public IWebElement TxtPassword => WebDriver.FindElement(By.Name("Password"));

        public IWebElement BtnLogin => WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn-default"));

        public IWebElement InkEmployeeDetails => WebDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Employee Details"));

        //public void ClickLogin() => InkLogin.Click();

        public void Login(string userid, string password)
        {
            TxtUserID.SendKeys(userid);
            TxtPassword.SendKeys(password);
        }

        public void ClickLoginButton() => BtnLogin.Submit();

        public bool IsEmployeeDetailsExist() => InkEmployeeDetails.Displayed;
    }
}
```

Also the same code but this time with UserID??

[image: Screenshot of the exception message]

Here is the errors it shown

```
dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
oasisLoginPage.Login((string)data.UserName, (string)data.Password);
```

I want to try both.

Comment: Is that compile time or runtime error?

Comment: What line of code does that error relate to?

Comment: click on image description

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. The bug is not in the code you have shown.

Comment: Please read the question I made some update

Comment: Is it supposed to be `UserName` or `UserId`?

Comment: Does `UserID` (capital D) work instead?

Comment: Both and UsedID I want to try the same code but this time with UserID is there another way of writing this code

Comment: Please read the questions that Greg Burghardt made edits on the code

Comment: The property name on the object must exactly match the column name in the SpecFlow data table. Try `(string)data.UserID` (with a capital 'D'). I bet that works. A few others have also asked you this.

Comment: No, it didn't work

Comment: I figure it out I have change my code         public void Login(string UserID, string Password)
        {
            TxtUserName.SendKeys(UserID);
            TxtPassword.SendKeys(Password);
And

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out I have change my code public void Login(string UserID, string Password) { TxtUserName.SendKeys(UserID); TxtPassword.SendKeys(Password); And Step Definition
dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
oasisLoginPage.Login((string)data.UserID, (string)data.Password);